# Regarding Residence permit in Germany

Tags: visas, schengen

I am Rajan and I study my master degree in Hof.

Due to my personal reason I came back to India last week and I will travel back to Germany on 31th of August 2017.

My Residence permit expires on 10th of September 2017.

My doubt is whether they will allow me to enter Germany on 31th August 2017, since my Residence permit expires 10 days from there ?

Could any please give me your feedback.

or

Could any share your experience if you have faced such situation.

Comment: Did you already apply for an extension (and have a proof of application)?

Comment: The important thing is your premise for enduring the cost of a round-trip from India for such a short period of time. Have you completed your course of study?

Comment: i am in india now and I have not applied yet but I am enrolled in university for next semester .

Answer (score 2):

They will almost certainly let you in, but be prepared to show a return ticket on the date before 10th of Sept or explain that you're planning to continue your studies and are about to apply for an extension within days.